# Hard drive is failing?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

Heard some clicking from my Sager NP8652 a few days ago and thought it might've been an HDD issue. Ran CrystalDiskInfo earlier today, and I got these results:
[image: http://gyazo.com/32f7b5eac4dc656c5037ece7b4a3bdf7]

About 12 hours later, here I am with a different diagnosis from CDI:
[image: http://gyazo.com/cc931b6450ebe9cc2b860fa709be1ec6])

I don't understand what it means and what I should do. If my hard drive needs to be replaced, what's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you performed a back up? This should be your #1 task if you do not have one done.

Answer (score 1):

The SMART 'reallocates sectors count' has fallen below a critical level (5). From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.):

> When the hard drive finds a read/write/verification error, it marks
>   that sector as "reallocated" and transfers data to a special reserved
>   area (spare area). This process is also known as remapping, and
>   reallocated sectors are called "remaps". The raw value normally
>   represents a count of the bad sectors that have been found and
>   remapped. Thus, the higher the attribute value, the more sectors the
>   drive has had to reallocate. This allows a drive with bad sectors to
>   continue operation; however, a drive which has had any reallocations
>   at all is significantly more likely to fail in the near future.

As already suggested by Carl B I would immediately take backup of your critical files, and keep any earlier backups. Then get a new replacement drive, connect it to your laptop with USB3-SATA adapter and clone the existing drive to it. The obvious cloning software to use is Clonezilla because it is opensource and free, though I have always used the (non-free, but available in trial version) [Casper](https://www.fssdev.com/products/casper/).

Once you have the cloned drive, time to open up the laptop and replace the existing drive with the new one.

If you don't need so much disk space and would like to give your laptop a big step-up, consider buying SSD as replacement.

Comment: Note that cloning makes a bit-for-bit copy, so all of the sectors that were bad and locked out on the old drive will get the same treatment on the new drive.  You might want to force a re-evaluation of bad sectors on the new drive.  I've never had to do it, so I don't want to recommend a specific method or product, but discussions should be easy to find with Google.  Also, if the spare sectors used for remapping have been exhausted on the old drive, I'm not sure if a clone will start out with these already exhausted on the new drive.  It's something to research or maybe someone can comment.

Comment: @fixer1234 Clonezilla may make a bit-for-bit copy, but Casper does not, it copies intelligently, and the paid-for version allows resizing of the filesystem (up or down).

Answer (score 0):

The drive is failing due to bad sectors. If you value your data on it - transfer whatever you can now as the dive is prone to failure sooner rather than later. You could try running chkdsk /r from the CMD to try to recover any data from those sectors and to isolate them, but this would probably extend the drive's life a little bit but not long. If these are software bad sectors, a simple format or "writing zeros" could fix it, but if there are actual physical bad sectors on the drive's platter - they cannot be fixed. 
I would not advise you to clone this drive as the process creates an exact copy of this drive with all its errors and bad sectors and the new drive would have to be reformatted in order to be used properly. 
I would suggest checking the warranty status of the drive and replacing it.